# Base de dados para site E-commerce

Tags: banco-de-dados, modelagem, e-commerce

Bom dia antes de mais, umas duvidas surgiram-me quando estáva a desenvolver a base de dados do meu site de vendas online(apenas para contexto de aulas...).
É o seguinte, tenho a tabela produtos, depois tenho o carrinho, fatura e pedidos, em todos eles tenho de guardar os produtos, apenas adiciono mais um campo nelas onde guardo o código do produto ? ou como temos uma outra tabela a liga-los por terem uma relação de muitos para muitos funciona de outra maneira? , estou meio confuso...whelp

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Você pode fazer uma tabela com códigos de produtos que remetem a um id especifico e aí no carrinho você puxa esses ids e coloca lá, e na fatura você puxa o codigo da fatura apenas. 
OBS: Cuidado na hora de puxar para não ter conflito de strings!

Comment: então pelo que percebi, tenho a tabela produtos com os códigos dos produtos, sendo um utilizador adicionava para o carrinho, então teria de criar um campo na tabela carrinho por exemplo "produtos" , já teria os produtos no carrinho, mesmo assim não percebi o que queria dizer com na fatura puxar apenas o código da fatura . obrigado por me responder.

Comment: Fui meio confuso, faça o seguinte, na tabela carrinho crie: produtos, lá você vai adicionar os ID's dos produtos, e nesse carrinho crie também o campo: codigo_do_carrinho(ou como quiser), depois na hora de pagar a fatura, você apenas recupera o valor codigo_do_carrinho e no select vc coloca: WHERE codigo_do_carrinho = $string

Comment: Ou você pode criar uma tabela totalmente nova que tenha os campos: id|usuario|codigo_do_carrinho|produto, e lá você a cada produto q for adicionado no carrinho e depois você puxa: FROM tabela WHERE usuario = $usuario

Comment: raphael caldas, obridadao por me ajudar, percebi o que me queria dizer e já sei como o vou fazer. ;) , abraço, tem um bom dia.